# Extension of Fourier transform to $L^2$ by density of Schwartz functions

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

The Fourier transform is usually extended to the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ space by invoking an argument that relies on the density of Schwartz functions in $L^2$.

Often, this extension is explicitly written as
$$ \hat{f} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \hat{f}_n \quad \text{(in } L^2),$$
where
$$\hat f_n(\nu) = \int_{[-n;+n]} f(t) e^{-2i\pi \nu t} \, dt,$$
with $f \in L^2$.

My question is: are the functions $\hat f_n(\nu)$ in that construction Schwartz? They are clearly $C^\infty$, but can one show that $\nu^k \hat f_n(\nu)$ vanishes at infinity for all $n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy why are you invoking the derivatives of $f$? I did not assume differentiability of that function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay, but I still don't understand this tip, since showing that the functions $\hat{f}_n$ are Schwartz is precisely what I want to do.

Comment: Yes, but here I still don't have a definition of the FT for an $L^2$ function.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I did not read the question properly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You mention the "density of Schwartz functions in $L^2$". Doesn't this mean that $f_n\in\mathcal{S}$ so that $\hat f_n\in\mathcal{S}$? Or is your problem understanding that the Fourier transform maps $\mathcal{S}$ to $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: No, it doesn't: it means instead that I can find functions in $S$ that are arbitrarily close (in $L^2$ norm) to $f_n$, but $f_n$ itself is not necessarily in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $f_n$ is certainly not a Schwarz function, even if $f$ is. (Regardless of whether it's been proved yet, the inversion theorem shows that ) $f_n=f\chi_{[-n,n]}$, not even continuous. (Hence $\hat f_n\notin L^1$.)

I don't see why it matters. I see people on MSE state that Plancherel is proved by using the Schwarz space this way, but I've never seen a book that actually takes that approach. Instead one just shows directly that $$||\hat f||_2=||f||_2\quad(f\in L^2\cap L^1),$$and then one notes that if $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ and $f_n=f\chi_{[-n,n]}$ then $f_n\in L^2\cap L^1$ and $||f-f_n||_2\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Yes, $f_n$ cannot be Schwartz, of course, but what about $\hat{f}_n(\nu)$ defined above?

Comment: @thetouristbr ??? All this is towards the Plancherel theorem, right? _If_ we using the Schwarz space to prove Plancherel surely we've already shown that the FT is an isomorphism on the Schwarz space...

Comment: My point is that I did not understand your $f_\nu$ notation.

Comment: (It seems that Duoandikoetxea's book has both approaches; Theorem 1.18, p15)